# j_security_check not redirecting to correct jsp

Tags: java, jsp, web.xml

I've been playing around with using `j_security_check` with jsp pages. When I hit the pages separately they all seem to work, however whenever I login It should redirect me to my `/index.jsp` but instead it just sends me to `/` which gives me a `404` since it doesn't exist.

Here is the code I have so far:

**web.xml**

```
<web-resource-collection id="WebResourceCollection_1">
    <web-resource-name>Management</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/login.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/error.jsp</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<!-- Login -->
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<!-- Welcome Files -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**login.jsp**

```
<form id="login" method="POST" action="j_security_check">

    <h1>Platform Sign-On</h1>
    <fieldset id="inputs">
        <input id="username" type="text" name="j_username" placeholder="Username" autofocus required>
        <input id="password" type="password" name="j_password" placeholder="Password" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="actions">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log in">
    </fieldset>

</form>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <div> HELLO WORLD </div>
</html>
```

As requested the folder structure is:

```
|/webapp
 |/WEB-INF
  |web.xml
 |login.jsp
 |error.jsp
 |index.jsp
```

Any ideas? I've been trying to figure out why they do not redirect on successful or unsuccessful login. It seems like everything is in place according to the resources I've read but they just don't seem to connect.

Comment: Could you post the folder structure?

Comment: sure, check it out!

Comment: You said that you can acess some pages...Give some examples of URLs you acessing

Comment: I mean I can access all those pages directly. i.e. in the browser I type localhost:8080/myapp/login.jsp, localhost:8080/myapp/error.jsp, localhost:8080/myapp/index.jsp. But  the login.jsp does not redirect login.jsp to index.jsp or error.jsp